# What means "bind c screen" in .screenrc config?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, dotfiles

I only want to understand what the lines in this .screenrc config does:

```
bind c screen 1
bind ^c screen 1
bind 0 select 10
screen 1
```

I found the config here:
[https://wiki.archlinux.org/](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNU_Screen#Start_at_window_1)

Through this my screen start at window 1 instead of 0. But I do not really understand what each line in this config does, also after reading the man page...

Help would be appreciated.